# Gremlin in W7 SP1

Tags: windows, windows-7, service-pack

for years W7 was fine.got error (0xc0000005) wouldn't go away. did fresh install, SP1, NET3.5.2, vc_redist2015 x86, all FBup, run a prog., ex:Winrar, not. Open browser again, not. error is back. quick restore and back to ok. Task Manager is normal. seen it so many times I could almost memorize each process. searched far and wide. most 'expert' sites are nothing more than copy and paste experts. any serious help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what the heck is "all FBup"? You could have a bad stick of RAM...

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  You should avoid "shorthand" code like "FBup", shorthand in general, should be avoid or explicitly explained in your question.  You can provide this additional detail by performing an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Error (0xc0000005) is often associated with hardware errors (Machine OK and then this error continues with reinstall of Windows).

The error also comes up for addressing errors and defective RAM could cause this.

I suggest getting the machine manufacturer's Hardware Test App and testing all the hardware. If there are hardware errors, it is likely time for a new computer.

[Windows 7 Error c0000005](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-code-0xc0000005-when-installing-windows-7/f9f699d4-c34b-4349-8ff4-be913bfde901?auth=1)

> Thanks for posting. The error code often means there is something
> physically wrong with the hard drive or RAM. If possible check with
> the OEM of your computer to see if there is a diagnostics for your
> hard drive.